# jQuery syncing attributes across multiple select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have three select menus with the same list of date slots in each, the purpose being for the user to select a first, second and third preference. I wish to prevent them from selecting a time slot more than once across all three select menus by disabling the selected options across all select menus. [My current solution](https://codepen.io/OinkQuack/pen/QxMQPd?editors=0010) works up to a point, but does not re-enable options once a different option is chosen.

I think I need to keep track of the checked options for all select menus so that I know which ones to re-enable when an option is changed.

I appreciate your attention in advance.

**HTML**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("select").change(function() {
    // Get index of selected option element
    let checkedIndex = $(':checked', this).index();
    // Loop through all option elements across all select elements
    $('option').each(function() {
      // Get index of all option elements
      let optionIndex = $(this).index();
      // If the selected option index matches another option
      if (optionIndex === checkedIndex) {
        let optionDisabled = $(this).prop('disabled');
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fsLocal" class="fsBody">
  <form method="post" novalidate action="#" class="fsForm fsSingleColumn fsMaxCol1" id="fsForm3097614">
    <div class="fsPage" id="fsPage3097614-1">
      <div class="fsSection fs1Col">
        <div class="fsSectionHeader">
          <h2 class="fsSectionHeading">Time slots</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="fsRow3097614-1" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
          <div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical fsSpan100" id="fsCell65519762" lang="en" fs-field-type="select">
            <label id="label65519762" class="fsLabel" for="field65519762">First preference </label>
            <select id="field65519762" name="field65519762" size="1" class="fsField">
              <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
              <option value="Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019">Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019">Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019">Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019">Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019">Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019">Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019">Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019">Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019">Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019">Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019">Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019">Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019">Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019">Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019">Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019">Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019">Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019">Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fsRow3097614-2" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
          <div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical fsSpan100" id="fsCell65519769" lang="en" fs-field-type="select">
            <label id="label65519769" class="fsLabel" for="field65519769">Second preference </label>
            <select id="field65519769" name="field65519769" size="1" class="fsField">
              <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
              <option value="Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019">Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019">Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019">Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019">Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019">Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019">Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019">Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019">Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019">Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019">Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019">Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019">Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019">Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019">Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019">Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019">Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019">Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019">Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="fsRow3097614-3" class="fsRow fsFieldRow fsLastRow">
          <div class="fsRowBody fsCell fsFieldCell fsFirst fsLast fsLabelVertical fsSpan100" id="fsCell65519770" lang="en" fs-field-type="select">
            <label id="label65519770" class="fsLabel" for="field65519770">Third preference </label>
            <select id="field65519770" name="field65519770" size="1" class="fsField">
              <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
              <option value="Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019">Slot 1: 1 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019">Slot 2: 4-8 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019">Slot 3: 11-15 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019">Slot 4: 18-22 Feb 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019">Slot 5: 25 Feb – 1 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019">Slot 6: 4-8 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019">Slot 7: 11-15 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019">Slot 8: 18-22 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019">Slot 9: 25-29 March 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019">Slot 10: 1-5 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019">Slot 11: 8-12 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019">Slot 12: 15-19 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019">Slot 13: 22-26 April 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019">Slot 14: 29 April – 3 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019">Slot 15: 6-10 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019">Slot 16: 13-17 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019">Slot 17: 20-24 May 2019</option>
              <option value="Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019">Slot 18: 27-31 May 2019</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyGMMK?editors=0010

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    var $selects = $('select');
    var $selectOptions = $selects.find('option');

    $selects.on('change', function() {
        // get all selected values in an array, remove the "Please select" empty values
        var selectedValues = $selects
            .find(':selected')
            .map(function() {
                return this.value;
            })
            .get()
            .filter(Boolean);

        // enable all
        $selectOptions.prop('disabled', false);

        // disable the selected values across all selects
        selectedValues.forEach(function(val) {
            $selects.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
        });

        // enable this value in this select
        $(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

There might be a better way, I don't write much jQuery these days.

Comment: Note: check changed HTML for `<option value="">Please select</option>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It certainly works. ;) I appreciate your time. I've not used the map method before; have to study it.

Comment: So, the map method converts the selected values to an array, but what does the get function do; that's Ajax, isn't it? I'm also unsure what a boolean find would do.

Comment: You're welcome. The `.get()` is not AJAX in this case, it's this: https://api.jquery.com/get/. Better explanation here: http://api.jquery.com/map/ - "As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.". `filter(Boolean)` removes all "falsy" values from the array, explanation here: http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array.

Comment: That's awesome, mate. I'll check out your links and edumicate myself. ;)